# How to scroll div with vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I put my slide div on the right top of page when scrolling vertical bar
here is Css my code

**CSS**

```
    <style>
              body {
                    width:100%;
                    overflow-x:hidden;
                    margin:0;
                }

              #slide {
                    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
                    width: 200px;
                    float: right;
                    margin-right: -180px;

                }
              p {
                color: red;
                margin: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
                float: right;   
                min-height: 200%;        
              }
              p:hover {
                background: yellow;
              }
</style>
```

Here is my HTML code
**HTML**

```
<body>
     <b>Jscript Animate Example</b>
     <div id="slide">

            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <p>First Paragraph</p>
        <p>Second Paragraph</p>
        <p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
</body>
```

my Jquery code
**Jquery**

```
<script>

             var menu = 0;
            $("#slide").click(function() {

                if (menu == 0) {
                    menu = 1;
                    $(this).animate(
                        {marginRight: '0px'},200
                    );
                } else {
                    menu = 0;
                    $(this).animate(
                        {marginRight: '-180px'},200
                    );
                }

            });
</script>
```

but when i scroll down, it moves on top.how can i fix it on top even i scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give it fixed position and top, right coordinates?

Comment: i have already tried it but doe to fix and it work but due to fixed i cant animate div using onclick event.

Comment: you should do the animation on container width and not on margin:
$(this).animate({width: '200px'}) // to show it
$(this).animate({width: '10px'}) // to hide most of it and leave only a sign that it's there

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    #slide {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

you can check it on http://jsfiddle.net/jU5YW/